# Converting char to int in C

Tags: c++, c, char, type-conversion

I have searched for this for quite some time before posting this question. The answer to it should be fairly easy though, since I am an ultra-beginner atm.

I have a `char*` in which I want a user to put some digits (over 20), that in turn can be called upon specifically.

This is what I've tried:

```
    char* digits = GetString();
    int prime = digits[0];
```

When I verify whether this worked with printf I find prime to have become 0.

```
    printf("prime:%d\ndigits:%c\n",prime, digits[0]);
```

Why would this be and what could I do to make this work?

Edit: Is it perhaps easier to make an int array and use GetLongLong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Neither C or C++ guarantees what value will be used to encode the character `0`, but both guarantee that digits will be contiguous and ordered, so (for example) `digits[0]-48` may or may not work, but `digits[0] - '0'` is guaranteed to work (presuming that `digits[0]` actually holds a digit, of course).

The precise requirement in the C++ standard (§2.3/3) is:

> In both the source and execution basic character sets, the value of each character after 0 in the
>   above list of decimal digits shall be one greater than the value of the previous.

At least as of C99, the C standard has identical wording, but at §5.2.1/3.

Comment: Thanks to both of you for your answer. For some reason prime keeps printing to be zero now. I've given up on the char solution for now but thanks for the effort!

Answer (score 2):

The character zero ('0') has the numeric value of 48, '1' is 49, and so on.

You may find this a useful idiom to get the numeric value from the ascii value.

```
int prime = digits[0] - '0';
```

You may also find looking at **man ascii** informative *(or similar man page if you use some other charset)*.

Comment: only on machines that use ascii for encoding. not all machines do.

Comment: Yes, I suppose if you find your self on the island of misfit toys and `man ascii` shows you nothing, try `man ebcdic`.

Comment: @JohnHascall: Not many use EBCDIC, but *many* use things like ISO 8859 and Shift JIS.